# Do I need to re-sign an apk to use appium for automating the blackbox test cases?

Tags: appium, black-box-testing

I have been exploring the android automation testing tools to automate black box testing where I would only have an apk without source code access. After spending some time with Robotium, I understood that it requires the user to re-sign an apk in order to automate. Hence I have decided to look into appium and still not very clear about how does it work? Is it possible to use appium to automate the tests where we  only have the target apk file without source code and if it is possible, is it required to resign it like Robotium.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate Android apk files using appium, as long as you have the apk binary.

iOS requires a signed developer build.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does it require to re-sign the apk?

Comment: Nope, don't need to re-sign.

Answer (score 0):

I have been pointed to read the "introduction" page of appium project instead of reading the "Getting Started" page and it indirectly clarifies the second question. (i.e., whether the apk needs to be re-signed in order to be used).

The #1 point in the introduction page states that "You shouldn't have to recompile your app or modify it in any way in order to automate it." So that means we do not need to re-sign the apk to automate with appium.